# jQuery Plugin for TinyMCE callback

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using the [jQuery plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_23.php) from the jQuery build of TinyMCE.
This simplified code initializes the editor:

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    script_url : '../js/libraries/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
});
```

This loads tiny_mce.js via AJAX.  I have code that I want to run once this file is loaded.
I essentially want to specify a callback function, but there is no mention of this in the [documentation for the plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:JQuery_Plugin_reference).

Any ideas?  I would be up for adding the functionality if it is not there but I cannot find an uncompressed version of the plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the `oninit` an option?  Looking at the minified source, the `oninit` runs after the ajax call comeback and the init runs.

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    script_url : '../js/libraries/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
    oninit: function() { alert("Loaded"); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could not get that much out of looking at the minified source

Comment: Thanks also, I was looking for this functionality but couldn't find it in their tutorial.